# embedded jetty "new Server(port)" throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, jetty, noclassdeffounderror

i try to develop a app on android with an embedded jetty to run some servlets.

What i did:
-imported the jetty-all-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar and configured the build path

in my mainActivity i use the following code:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setDescriptor(context+"/WEB-INF/web.xml");
context.setResourceBase(".");
context.setContextPath("/");
context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
```

but my app suspends at the first line with the following stack:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NoClassDefFoundError))  
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    MainActivity.onCreate(Bundle) line: 175 
    MainActivity(Activity).performCreate(Bundle) line: 4465 
    Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity, Bundle) line: 1049   
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2033    
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2104 
    ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 132    
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1157  
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 137 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4575    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 789  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 556 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is an i-jetty project at https://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/ you could take a look at, it is jetty 7 atm I believe.  Once android supports java 7 I think there are plans to get jetty 9 working on it.